# Displaying value of ADDLOCAL property on the UI

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

Using WiX, I would like to display the list of features that were installed at the end of the MSI installation.  When using full UI mode, the user will select the features to install by using a feature tree.  Looking at the log, the ADDLOCAL property is updated appropriately and is displayed in the log as a comma-delimited list of features.  However, when I try to display this value on the UI, it appears blank.  If I try launching the MSI in full UI mode via the command prompt and pass in a value for ADDLOCAL, this value is the one displayed on the UI, even if the user modifies the feature selection via the feature tree.  How can I display to the user on a dialog what features were installed?

Answer (score 2):

Add following line to your wix source code:

```
<SetProperty Id="FEATURELIST" Value="[ADDLOCAL]" After="CostFinalize"/>
```

And use `FEATURELIST` property to get list of all installed features.

That’s really it. :)

Comment: I did what you suggested and I still cannot display the information.  When I double-click on the MSI, set the features to install using the feature tree, set a FEATURELIST property to [ADDLOCAL], and look at the log, the FEATURELIST property is correct - it is a comma-delimited list of features to be installed.  However, if I try to display this list, it is blank.  Perhaps I am doing that part incorrectly? 'Text="This should be the text: [FEATURELIST]"'

Answer (score 0):

Properties are case sensitive make sure to use caps like this ADDLOCAL Hope this helps!